# Buil Android Lite Version

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an Android game, and want to release a Lite version with limited features as well.  Is there a way I can configure Eclipse to build a second package?  Or will I have to have a separate set of code to build the lite version?

Answer (score 4):

Use an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject).

Comment: Android library project isnt really what i'm looking for, since I would basically end up copy pasting the files into a different folder to create a new eclipse project to build the other package

Comment: @starphoenix: "f you are creating an application that exists in both free and paid versions. You move the part of the application that is common to both versions into a library project. The two dependent projects, with their different package names, will reference the library project and provide only the difference between the two application versions." (from the documentation that I linked to above).

Comment: I was looking for a solution that didnt involve multiple projects, but it seems either way I go, with either a library project, or just two separate code projects, I end up with multiple eclipse projects

Comment: @starphoenix If you use Android Library, you will have 3 different eclipse projects(Library Project, Application-Lite Project, Application- Full Project), but you dont have to be concerned about making common code changes in all the projects.